# How can I make this subcategories vertical menu work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need some subcategories on this menu but I don't know why doesn't work. This is my menu. I tried to do like this:

```
<ul id="accordion">
    <li>Main</li>
        <ul>
            <li>Link1</li>
            <li>Link2</li>
            <ul id="accordion">
                        <li>link</li>
                        <li>link</li>
            </ul>
        </ul>
</ul>
```

But I don't understand why doesn't show the subcategory.

This is where should appairs:

```
<?php
ob_start (); // Buffer output
?>
<html>
<head>
<title><!--TITLE--></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="it" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />  
    <meta name="keywords" content="<!--KEYWORDS-->" />
    <meta name="description" content="<!--DESCRIPTION-->" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="template/style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="banner"><?php include('template/banner.php') ?></div>
            <div id="navigation_left"><?php include("template/link_left.php") ?></div>      
            <div id="navigation_right" align="left"><?php include("template/link_right.php") ?></div>                               
            <div id="content"><?php include("$page.php") ?> </div>
            <div id="footer"><?php include('template/footer.php') ?></div>
        </div>
</body>
<SCRIPT>
$("#accordion > li").click(function(){

    if(false == $(this).next().is(':visible')) {
        $('#accordion > ul').slideUp(300);
    }
    $(this).next().slideToggle(300);
});
</SCRIPT>
</html>
<?php
$pageContents = ob_get_contents (); // Get all the page's HTML into a string
ob_end_clean (); // Wipe the buffer

// Replace <!--TITLE--> with $pageTitle variable contents, and print the HTML
$pageContents = str_replace ('<!--TITLE-->', $pageTitle, $pageContents);
$pageContents = str_replace ('<!--DESCRIPTION-->', $pageDescription, $pageContents);
echo str_replace ('<!--KEYWORDS-->', $pageKey, $pageContents);

?>
```

accordion is contained in template/style.css

```
#accordion {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
}
#accordion li{
    display: block;
    background-color: #FF9927;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 1px;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 5 5 5 7px;
}
#accordion ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    display: none;
}
#accordion ul li{
    font-weight: normal;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 0 0 0 7px;
}
#accordion a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#accordion a:hover {
    margin-left:5px;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

I think I should add something on the script but I don't know what.

Comment: First of all, you can't have two elements with the same `id`.

Comment: There is also a big problem with `ul` in `ul` in `ul`. You need to add every `ul` in a `li`. `ul > li > ul > li > ul` instead of `ul >  ul > ul > li`. It's not valid code and it probably breaks the browser interpretation

Comment: Nick Manning: Yes, of course I can't. I copied first 'ul' and I forgot to delete 'id'.
OxyDesign: I didn't know that. I tried to see the structure with an editor html and was "correct". I didn't know that I could have problems with browser interpretation. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this fits for you :

http://jsfiddle.net/OxyDesign/ctL47w6c/

HTML

```
<ul id="accordion">
    <li>Main
        <ul>
            <li>Link1</li>
            <li>Link2
                <ul>
                    <li>link</li>
                    <li>link</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#accordion li").click(function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
        var subList = $(this).find('> ul');
        if(subList.length) subList.slideToggle(300);
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't understand why if I declare this script on a file menu.js and I recall it with '<script type="text/javascript" src="menu.js"></script>' or if I put between '<script>' tag in 'head' doesn't work, while if I put after '</body' works. I know that all script should be included between '<head></head>'. I'm validating code and it display this problem

Comment: You need to encapsulate it in a document ready (I updated the answer and the jsfiddle to add it). If you don't do that and let your js in the head (not recommended because it stops the rendering of the page until all the JS are parsed) it will try to find the `"#accordion li"` but there are not present yet.

Comment: I got it! Just a clarification: you said: not recommended because it stops the rendering of the page until all the JS are parsed. This means that I shouldn't to put the js file between "<head>"?  But if I don't do this W3C will always return an error. After that, we've done. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Put the `<script></script>` at the end, just before the closing `</body>`. Like this, it's valid and the rendering html/css is done before the script loads.

Comment: That's what I thougth.
line 110 column 57 - Errore: document type does not allow element "script" here
I declared the page as
"<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">"
"<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">"

Comment: I tried to validate `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
 <title>Test JS</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div></div>
 <script type="text/ajavscript">
 //JS
 console.log('script in the body');
 </script>
</body>
</html>` in http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input and it says "passed"

Comment: I loaded on my server. Look:
http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.fullmetalpanic-italy.com%2Finc%2Findex.php&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0
Is just code. Doesn't work from browser.

Comment: I checked the source and the `<script></script>` is just after the `</body>` and it has to be just before to be valid.

Comment: Wait...Before `</body>` or after? Before is valid, after no